# How table of strings works?

Tags: c, pointers, compilation

I was searching about this code that I didn't believe that works, but I found something in books about table of strings that exists in compiler.

```
char *p;
p = "something";

printf("%s", p);
```

How this code works ?

Comment: First you should read about C-pointers. If you are used to them, maybe you should reword the question if it isn't then clear to you already.

Comment: `p` points to the string "something" and `printf` prints the string. That's how things work in C, you should read a book about C, pointer, strings and/or follow a tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"something"` is a *string literal*, which is a null-terminated character array that is stored in read-only memory. `p` is a pointer to char. Since you set this pointer to point at read-only memory, you should always declare it as `const char*`.

`sizeof(p)` gives the size of p. `p` is a pointer so you get the size of a pointer, 4 bytes on your specific system.

Had you instead declared an array `char arr[] = "something";` you would have gotten a copy of something stored in your local array, where you can also modify it. And if you take sizeof an array, you get the expected size. In the array case `sizeof(arr)` would give you 9+1=10 bytes.

For reference, please read:

[What is the difference between char s[] and char *s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)

[Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char *s" but not "char s[]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Comment: I read the reference that you showed. So, the string literal `"something"` is in read-only memory (the program allocates memory for it ? i.e. 9+1 bytes ?) and a pointer to char `p` is in the read-write memory ? It was what I read in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Data

Answer (score 1):

```
char *p = "something";
```

This is read only so you are able to print it.

```
sizeof(p);
```

You are printing the sizeof pointer not the size of the string.

Comment: @X0R40 Read this link you will be able to understand what happens
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go